# Is the set where $\mathrm{dist}(x,\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\})$ is not differentiable a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose that $ A=\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}$  and $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\inf \{|y-x|;y \in A\}$.  Let $K$ be the set of points where $f$ is not differentiable. Is $K$ closed? Can $K$ be specified?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Draw the graph of $f$. You’ll find that it’s made up of (infinitely many) straight line segments, and that the part of it between $0$ and $1$ zigzags up and down, with sharp corners at certain points. Those points where it has corners are places where $f$ is not differentiable.

Once you’ve seen what’s happening on a sketch, it shouldn’t be too hard to say exactly what the set $K$ is.

Comment: k=A+ {0}?? is true?

Comment: @narges: $A\cup\{0\}\subseteq K$, but $K$ has infinitely many other points as well. Look at the graph of $f$ between $x=\frac12$ and $x=1$; can you find another sharp corner in that interval?

Comment: @narges: $\frac14\in A$, so yes, $\frac14\in K$; but there are infinitely many points in $K$ that are **not** in $A$. One of them is between $\frac12$ and $1$; can you find it?

Comment: 5/12?  is true??

Comment: 1\2( 1/n + 1/(n+1))? yes?

Comment: @narges: Yes, $\frac5{12}\in K$, because $\frac5{12}$ is halfway between the points $\frac13$ and $\frac12$ in $A$; the graph of $f$ has a sharp peak at $x=\frac5{12}$. Yes, it’s the points halfway between $\frac1n$ and $\frac1{n+1}$.

Comment: then k is closed,yes?

Comment: is limits points of k {0}?

Comment: @narges: Yes, $K$ is closed: it consists of $A$, $\{0\}$, and the points halfway between adjacent points of $A$.

Comment: @narges: You’re very welcome.